# Pluggable database not showing the users tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have oracle 19c multitenant and asm installed.
When I create a container and a pluggable database
by graphic view I can see the users tablespace from the database.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> alter session set container=PDBORCL;
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;
TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
USERS
```

But if I create a container and plugable database in silent mode,
I can only see the users tablespace from the container and if I enter the pluggable database, I can't see the users tablespace.

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> alter session set container=TESTPDB;
SQL> select tablespace_name from dba_tablespaces;
TABLESPACE_NAME
------------------------------
SYSTEM
SYSAUX
UNDOTBS1
TEMP
```

I used these commands to create the container and the database

```
dbca -silent -createDatabase -databaseConfigType SINGLE -databaseType MULTIPURPOSE \
-templateName General_Purpose.dbc -gdbName TEST -sid TEST -createAsContainerDatabase true \
-useLocalUndoForPDBs true -storageType ASM -datafileDestination +DTA01 -recoveryAreaDestination +FRA01 \
-useOMF true -recoveryAreaSize 9000 -memoryMgmtType AUTO_SGA -totalMemory 4000 \ 
-characterSet AL32UTF8 -nationalCharacterSet AL16UTF16 -emConfiguration NONE -systemPassword Redhat123 \
-sysPassword Redhat123 -redoLogFileSize 200
```

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE TESTPDB ADMIN USER usradminapp IDENTIFIED BY Redhat123 FILE_NAME_CONVERT = ('+DTA01', '+DTA01 ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query bellow to check the default tablespace in your pdb:

```
SELECT PROPERTY_NAME, PROPERTY_VALUE
FROM DATABASE_PROPERTIES
WHERE PROPERTY_NAME IN ('DEFAULT_PERMANENT_TABLESPACE','DEFAULT_TEMP_TABLESPACE');
```

You can re-create the pdb and adding the option "default tablespace" to see if it can solve your problem:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/overview-of-pdb-creation.html#GUID-5FC7BAB3-65DE-47E2-9ED7-1093ED784A3C